# Any way to connect 3 external displays to a 2018 Retina MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

Just wondering if there's any docking solution that provides the possibility to connect to 3 external displays to the MacBook Air 2018, or if we're hardware limited by the iGPU here.

Comment: Can’t you daisy chain them with DisplayPort cables?

Comment: @Wildcard [MacOS doesn't support MST/daisy-chaining at the software level](https://medium.com/@sebvance/everything-you-need-to-know-about-macbook-pros-and-their-lack-of-displayport-mst-multi-stream-98ce33d64af4)

Comment: Thank you! So is my question looking like a no then?

Comment: Your MBA 2018 intel gpu won't handle correctly even 1x 4K@60hz monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a "native" display signal, the 2018 Retina MacBook Air is limited to 2 external monitors.

However, you can use other types of displays such as a USB display to act as a third monitor. They are generally limited in resolution, update frequency, GPU performance, etc. - so do not expect to be able to play 3D games or use 4k resolution on such a display.

If you want higher performance for the third display, you can connect an eGPU to the MacBook Air which would enable you to use more monitors with higher performance. Such a setup is usually quite more costly than a USB display however.

Comment: Thank you! I think something like this would do the trick for the last monitor. So it's USB displays I should be looking into for MacOS?

Comment: It doesn’t matter if you want to run macOS, Windows or something else - the limitation is the same. What type of display to look for really depends on what you want to use it for?

Comment: Gotcha. I think with your suggestion this will do the trick:
https://www.amazon.ca/Plugable-Charging-Delivery-Specific-Thunderbolt/dp/B01FKTZLBS

As Apple seems to have fixed the compatibility issues with DisplayLink devices in 10.14.2: https://plugable.com/2018/03/30/macos-10-13-4-disables-displaylink-duet-display-devices/

Comment: @JamesMyers There seems to be some confusing as to which computer you actually have. Your question says "MacBook Air", but the product you've found seems to suggest that you have a "Retina MacBook Air" (i.e. with USB-C connectors). Which computer do you have?

Comment: I think the dock I linked above is gonna do the trick, but for reference I was referring to the Macbook Air with Retina Display. I honestly had no idea Apple was still selling the legacy model.